# Available suitable solutions for web app importing DWG || DXF files?

Tags: .net, web-applications, autocad

I need directions to what are possible solutions for web app handling autoCAD files(importing).

The app will have to render 2D architectural plans from imported autoCAD files with possibility to move walls, furniture etc.

I was thinking about using Unity with webGL build, as I already know it, but it's not a perfect tool for simple 2d application and there will be a problem(as always) with external .NET DWG/DXF handling libraries(old mono won't compile most(if not every) of libraries out there).

As an alternative I found this nice little engine - http://www.babylonjs.com/ - which also builds webGL apps, but much smaller and many times faster loading. But I have no idea if it's possible to use external libraries for it to handle autoCAD files. Any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Forge translator and viewer](http://developer.autodesk.com) on your website. The rest service, [Model Derivative](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2), translate a .DWG into a json stream that can viewed on browsers with uses WebGL and [Three.js](https://threejs.org/).

There are many examples at this [github org](https://github.com/autodesk-forge/), but [this sample](https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit3d) implements something similar to what you described for Revit models.